# How can i move svn root repository to different file system?

Tags: linux, git, svn, centos, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to move my svn root repository because my current svn file system size is low, so only i am moving to different file system. last two days i am searching about that but i am not clear. my environment configurations is a follows below,

```
OS : Centos 6
svn version: svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
root directory: /var/www/svn/
File System Details: 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             9.9G  8.2G  1.2G  88% /
tmpfs                 5.7G   72K  5.7G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             9.9G  8.2G  1.3G  87% /usr
/dev/sda3             9.9G  8.8G  557M  95% /var
/dev/sda6             422G   61G  339G  16% /data
```

I want to move svn root repository from "/var" to "/data" file system.
please help me... what is the command to change svn root repository.
Advance in Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. From filesystem's POV,  repository on server is just directory (subdir of `/var/www/svn/` or `/var/www/svn/` directly - it isn't clear from description and wrong used lingua). In order to change physical location, you have just `mv SRC DEST` and later change configuration of used (if any) Subversion server (`-r` option for svnserve, SVNPath|SVNParentPath for Apache)